# Atom disable tooltip when hovering over function signature

Tags: python, atom-editor

When using the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor, when I hover my mouse over a function signature, a tool-tip appears (see image below):

[image: picture of overlay/tooltip]

How can I disable it?

Thank you, happy to supply more info as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Ide Python package, you can disable Jedi Hover option in it's settings.